# get matrix object from previous bars (historical)

Tags: pine-script

variable of type matrix cannot be used with the operator [] does not support it?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Test", shorttitle="test", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
a = matrix.new<int>(columns=3, rows = 2)
plot(matrix.rows(a[0]) , title = "test")
```

Message Error:
Cannot call 'operator SQBR' with argument 'expr0'='a'. An argument of 'matrix' type was used but a 'series na' is expected

Comment: What are you trying to plot?

Answer (score 0):

It does not support it. Use this:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Test", shorttitle="test", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

a = matrix.new<int>(columns=3, rows = 2)

rowSize = matrix.rows(a)

plot(rowSize[1] , title = "test")
```